# Adding DataRow into a New Datatable error saying the row is already associated to a table

Tags: c#, datatable, datarowview

I am using the below code in Visual Studios to go through each DataRow in a table and include an If statement to say where if a certain criteria is met, it creates a DataRow. I then want that DataRow to then be added into dt_tempHold for use later on in my program. Is "dt_tempHold.Rows.Add(dr_EPA);" not the thing to use here because I get an error saying that the row already belongs to another table? I just want a copy of the DataRow, into the DataTable as it goes through the ForEach and the If statements.

```
        DataTable dt_tempHold = new DataTable();

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds_picsData.Tables["Placemnt"].Rows)
        {
            if (ds_spreadsheetdata.Tables["EPABase"].AsEnumerable().Any(t => t.Field<string>("EPA_ORG_ID") == dr["NAME"].ToString()))
            {

                DataRow dr_EPA = ds_spreadsheetdata.Tables["EPABase"].AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Field<string>("EPA_ORG_ID") == dr["NAME"].ToString());

                dt_tempHold.Rows.Add(dr_EPA);

                dr["ADDR1"] = dr_EPA["Contact_address1"].ToString();
                dr["ADDR2"] = dr_EPA["Contact_address2"].ToString();
                dr["ADDR3"] = dr_EPA["Contact_address3"].ToString();
                dr["ADDR4"] = dr_EPA["Contact_address4"].ToString();
                dr["POSTCODE"] = dr_EPA["Postcode"].ToString();
                dr["PHONE"] = dr_EPA["Contact_number"].ToString();
                dr["EMAIL"] = dr_EPA["Contact_email"].ToString();
                dr["NAME"] = dr_EPA["EP_Assessment_Organisations"].ToString();



            }

        };
```

Comment: You say "it creates a DataRow", but where does it do that? I see no creation of a new DataRow in the code you've posted. Instead, you're finding a DataRow in one table, and add that row to another table, which is giving you this exception. Can you verify that you didn't lose a line of code somewhere?

Comment: You should create a new row using `NewRow()` method of `DataTable`

Comment: Ah, ok. I assumed that  "DataRow dr_EPA =" etc was the creation of the DataRow. The comment made after yours Lasse, might be what i'm looking for. Thanks Pavel.

Comment: @Jay no, that fetches an *existing* `DataRow` from another table, so indeed: sounds like exactly the problem

Comment: Side note: `DataTable` tends to be *massively* over-used, especially by people starting out in .NET; in reality, almost *anything else* is preferable to `DataTable` in most scenarios. If anything `DataTable` was a migration utility to help people migrate from ADO (record-sets) to ADO.NET, but... that was 15+ years ago, and that isn't what most people are doing.